# how to decode the encoded array passed from php

Tags: php, python, arrays, json

I have problem in decoding the array passed from PHP. My PHP code is

```
$checkedJson = json_encode($dynamic_species);
$tmp = exec("/Python33/arr_pass.py $pressure $temp $checkedJson");
return $tmp;
```

If i print $checkedJson i get

> {"species1":"CH4","species2":"C2H6"} as print statement

My python code is

```
species_list = sys.argv[3]
species_list_data = json.loads(species_list)
print(species_list_data['species1'])
```

This python script returns empty string as output to php

I am working for first time on JSON can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is neither a JSON nor Python question. What you want is to figure out how to get output back when your PHP program runs something via `exec()`. Basically you're lacking the output parameter; RTM at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). You should try:

```
exec("/Python33/arr_pass.py $pressure $temp $checkedJson", $output);
```

After which `$output` will be an array of lines that your exec'd script sent to its output. In your code, `$tmp` is assigned to the last line that the exec'd thing prints, so probably an empty line.

Plus you have one more challenge; the way you pass `$checkdJson` to the Python script will fail. You will have to quote it to make it one commandline parameter, so you'll probably need

```
exec("/Python33/arr_pass.py $pressure $temp '$checkedJson'", $output);
```

(note the extra single quotes).

Comment: still  no change $output returns as array(0) and $tmp is empty string

Comment: What happens when you add in PHP a `print` statement to see what is actually happening, as `print("/Python33/arr_pass.py $pressure $temp '$checkedJson'")`? Then take that output and run it on the command line in a terminal. Does that work as you'd expect?

Comment: print("/Python33/arr_pass.py $pressure $temp '$checkedJson'") outputs as /Python33/arr_pass.py 534 5'{"species1":"FDGD","species2":"DFG"}'.I tested it on command line it works as i expected.but when i print print(sys.argv[3]) in python the output in php shows '{species1:SDF2,species2:SFS}', that means sys.argv[3] format is changed from '{"species1":"FDGD","species2":"DFG"}' to '{species1:SDF2,species2:SFS}'. Please let me know if you need more clear explanation

Comment: I don't know where that quote-stripping behavior comes from, but it's not good. A valid JSON representation must have the double quotes. I suspect that's why Python doesn't want to process it...

Comment: :There was problem in my array i think now got the expected output Thank you